# OCaml Syntax Error in let..in

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ocaml

I am new to Ocaml and I am trying to print out an AST tree, however I am getting a syntax error at the `in` of the `mon_to_string` function. 
Note: All the functions used are defined.

```
let rec print exp =
  let rec the_exp tree out = match tree with
    [] -> out

  and exp_to_string tree = match tree with
    | Ast.Expression.Identifier(x) -> print_identifier x
    | Ast.Expression.Literal(x) -> print_literal x
    | Ast.Expression.BinaryExp(x) -> print_bin_exp x
    | Ast.Expression.UnaryExp(x) -> print_unary_exp x
  in "<Expression>\n" ^ exp_to_string exp ^ "</Expression>\n"

  and mon_to_string tree = match tree with
    | Ast.Monitor.ExpressionGuard(x) -> print_exp_guard x
    | Ast.Monitor.QuantifiedGuard(x) -> print_quant_guard x
    | Ast.Monitor.Conditional(x) -> print_conditional x
    | Ast.Monitor.Evaluate(x) -> print_eval x
    | Ast.Monitor.Choice(x) -> print_choice x
  in "<Monitor>" ^ "\n" ^ mon_to_string exp ^ "</Monitor>\n"
```

Comment: You cannot have two `in`s with only one `let`. Which is the expression that the outer `print` is supposed to return?

Comment: Your code has NO syntax error.  You should post the error message, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `let` corresponding to the last `in`.

The correct syntax goes like this:

```
let rec v1 = exp1
and v2 = exp2
and v3 = exp3
in exp4
```

You have:

```
let rec v1 = exp1
and v2 = exp2
in exp3
and v3 = exp4
in exp5
```